# Is ADATA XPG SX6000 512GB PCIe Gen3x2 M.2 2280 SSD compatible with Alienware 17 R3?

Tags: ssd

Is **ADATA XPG SX6000 PCIe 512GB PCIe Gen3x2 M.2 2280 NVMe SSD** compatible with Alienware 17 R3? According to the specification, Alienware 17 R3 supports **PCIe Gen3x4** but this SSD is of **PCIe Gen3x2**. Is PCIe Gen3x2 is compatible on Gen3x4 slot. Kindly throw some light on it.
Advance thanks!!